# International macros in Excel

Tags: excel, internationalization, vba

I'm trying to create an international Excel macro sheet.
These macros should work for many countries

I'm writing formulas in English using `Range.formula`, but it does not work for all formulas (?)

For example, I create

```
Range("D4").Formula = "=SUM(D7:D14)"
```

In Spanish Excel it works so is filled with "`=SUMA(D7:D14)`". Is correct

Other formulas fails, for example:

```
"=IF(R2=8;D7;D6)"                  'In Spanish Excel I get error 1004

"=ISNUMBER(O2)" works =ESNUMERO(O2)

"=PRODUCT(O2;O3)" Does not work,  error 1004
```

I'm with Excel 2010 and Windows 7 , and I cannot understand this strange behavior. Parameters are valid for all formulas

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with ATP functions                                                                                           https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983034

Answer (score 3):

`Range.Formula` expects English formula notation. This means not only English function names but also using comma to separate parameters and not semicolon.

So

`...Formula = "=IF(R2=8,D7,D6)"`

and

`...Formula = "=PRODUCT(O2,O3)"`

should work.